# Сортировка массива php по значению

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите пожалуйста, есть массив product из товаров в котором содержится (id,title ,price и др.) , как можно его отсортировать по значению "price " ?

```
 <? foreach (  $volumes as $key => $product ) { ?>
        <div><?= $product['product']->price; ?> </div>
 <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usort($volumes,function($a,$b){
    return $a['product']->price - $b['product']->price;
});
```

Comment: Подскажите пжл правильно ли я делаю: <? 


foreach (  $volumes as $key => $product ) { 
 echo  $product['product']->price;
}
usort($volumes,function($a,$b){
return $a['product']->price - $b['product']->price;
});
 
 ?>

Comment: @Kirill, нет, сначала сортируем через [usort](http://www.php.su/usort()), потом выводим.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете sql таблицу для хранения данных (что следует из тегов) могу порекомендовать метод 'order by'
Например: 'select * from Volumes order by Price;'. это выстроит получаемые значения по цене от меньшего к большему.
Если же нужно наоборот от большего к меньшему - 'select * from Volumes order by Price desc;'